# cast to pointer to array - c vs. c++ (or gcc vs. g++)

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc

The following code compiles (and works as expected) when compiled as c code (gcc with file suffix '.c') but throws an error when compiled as c++ code (g++ of gcc with file suffix '.cpp'):

```
int sum_square_matrix(int *matrix, int size) {
    int (*m)[size] = (int(*)[])matrix;
    ...
}
```

The following error is thrown when compiled with g++ (or gcc with suffix .cpp):

```
c_vs_cpp.c:4:32: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[]’ to ‘int (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)size) + -1)) + 1)]’ in initialization
     int (*m)[size] = (int(*)[])matrix;
```

The motivation behind such code is processing a square matrix as a double dimension array when the dimension is not known in advance.

So my questions are:

1. Is there anything in the c++ standard different from the c standard that makes this casting illegal?
2. Any other suggested method for acheiving the same goal (other than manually accessing the elements in the matrix using ugly arithmetics and service functions). Preferably a common way that is supported in both c/c++.

Comment: Why do you expect a different language to behave the same as C? Just beacuse they use similar santax, C and C++ are different languages. Note that, depending on the caller the code invokes undefined behaviour in C, too.

Comment: They are two different languages. It is like comparing Spanish with Portuguese. Both have same heritage but are two different languages

Comment: I disagree with the downvotes, and (@Olaf) on the removal of the C tag. The question is specifically asking for differences between C and C++, and how to write code that works for both.

Comment: @FabioTurati: The question asks why code does not work in C++. Which is clearly a distinct language. The DVs are most likely because the question is badly research, including assuming C and C++ behave identical without justification.

Comment: The  easy and compatible way is to do the index calculations explicitly.

Comment: In C99, 11, you could use variable-length arrays, provided that the ordering of the arguments were reversed

Comment: Why not try java and c++? Both have similar syntax

Comment: Might as well ask why lesbians don't date men.

Comment: So you ask if there are differences between different languages. Some questions son't show even a little effort.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile a program with the wrong compiler?

Comment: Relating to 'C' and C++ as just "two different languages" is wrong.This is not Java and C++. C++ originated from C and there was a clear intent and obvious motivation (including the ability to migrate code from 'C' to 'C++' to preserve common ground. You are welcome to read Stroustrup section 1.6 relating to this. So where this assumption does not apply there may be intended reason for this, or as I now understand from the thorough answer provided  @user2079303 that the support in the case of 'C' was added after the branch.

Comment: @EdHeal There are lots of companies that work in the embedded world and that keep working on different products, as requested by customers, and in some cases they work on a CPU for which there's a C++ compiler, but in other cases there's only a C one, so they try to have a common code base that compiles with both. C and C++ don't just have "similar syntax" or "same heritage". Sure, it doesn't work in both ways, but writing C code that also works when compiled as C++ is possible. Not always, and it isn't necessarily easy, but it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is there anything in the c++ standard different from the c standard that makes this casting illegal?

Yes. C++ standard doesn't allow variable length arrays †. C standard does (since C99).

> 2. Any other suggested method for acheiving the same goal (other than manually accessing the elements in the matrix using ugly arithmetics and service functions).

It's pretty trivial to wrap the ugly arithmetics inside a helper type. A simple example:

```
template<class T>
struct matrix_view
{
    T* matrix;
    size_t size;

    T* operator[](size_t i) {
        return matrix + i * size;
    }
};

template<class T>
auto
make_matrix_view(T* matrix, size_t size)
{
    return matrix_view<T>{matrix, size};
}

int sum_square_matrix(int *matrix, int size) {
    auto m = make_matrix_view(matrix, size);
    // ...
}
```

With some more boilerplate you can make `matrix_view` usable in standard algorithms and range based loops too (only the outer loop though; the inner loop isn't quite so trivial).

> Preferably a common way that is supported in both c/c++.

Perhaps you could design a macro that uses the shown matrix_view in c++ and whatever cast method is supported in C.

---

† GCC does support VLA as a language extension, which is why your error message doesn't say it as the reason for the error. For whatever reason, the C++ implementation doesn't agree with your conversion. It apparently does if you state the size in the cast:

```
int (*m)[size] = (int(*)[size])matrix;
```

I don't think this has anything to do with the C++ standard though, just a difference between standard C and GCC implementation of VLA extension for C++.